# Physical significance of the string anti-symmetric tensor field?

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, axion

I've been looking at David Tong's [Lectures on String Theory](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html).

Is the anti-symmetric tensor field $B_{\mu\nu}$ (Eqn. 2.29) of string theory related to the electromagnetic field?

Also I've seen $B_{\mu\nu}$ refered to as an axion field. Is it related to the hypothetical QCD axion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since (super)string theory lives in 10 dimensions and you need compactification to get a 4d theory out of it, nothing in its uncompactified field content is *directly* related to elements of the 4d Standard Model.

The B-field or Kalb-Ramond field is a 2-form $\mathrm{U}(1)$-gauge field, i.e. it is "like" the Yang-Mills theory of electromagnetism but with a 2-form gauge potential instead of the 1-form vector potential of ordinary electrodynamics. The general theory of such fields is called "higher gauge theory".

The moniker "axion field" is indeed related to QCD axions and likely originates from Witten's and Svreck's [*"Axions in String Theory"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0605206), where they Calabi-Yau compactify heterotic string theory to 4 dimensions and observe that some components of the $B$-field have the right structure to become axion-like fields in the compactification. Additionally model-dependent axions can arise from zero modes of the B-field on the compactification manifold, but this depends on the specific manifold chosen (since zero modes are closely related to (co)homology).